# How to deal with that kind of errors and why it occurred?(Memory Limit Exceeded)

Tags: java, algorithm, arraylist, data-structures

This is a leetcode problem.
When running my code in eclipse everything is fine but when i submit it to leetcode error occurs "Memory Limit Exceeded" .How to deal with it .

Given a list of airline tickets represented by pairs of departure and arrival airports [from, to], reconstruct the itinerary in order. All of the tickets belong to a man who departs from JFK. Thus, the itinerary must begin with JFK.

Note:

If there are multiple valid itineraries, you should return the itinerary that has the smallest lexical order when read as a single string. For example, the itinerary ["JFK", "LGA"] has a smaller lexical order than ["JFK", "LGB"].
All airports are represented by three capital letters (IATA code).
You may assume all tickets form at least one valid itinerary.

Here is my solution:

```
class Solution {
    class Checker implements Comparator<String>{
        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            return o1.compareToIgnoreCase(o2);
        }
    }
    public List<String> findItinerary(List<List<String>> tickets){
        String begin="JFK";
        final String example=begin;
        List<String> solution = new ArrayList<>();
        long counter=tickets.stream().filter(lister->lister.get(0).equals(example)).count();
        List<String> lexic=tickets.stream().filter(lister->lister.get(0).equals("JFK")).map(p->p.get(1)).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
        Comparator<String> comparator =new Checker();
        lexic.sort(comparator);
        solution.add(begin);
        begin=lexic.get(0);
        System.out.println(counter);
        for(int i=0;i<tickets.size();i++) {
            if(tickets.get(i).get(0).equals(begin)) {
                if(!solution.contains(begin)) {
                    solution.add(begin);
                }
                begin=tickets.get(i).get(1);
                solution.add(begin);
                i=-1;
            }
        }
        return solution;
    }

}
```

Comment: The `lexic` list looks unnecessary: just use `min` instead of collecting to a list, sorting, and taking the first element.

Comment: @Andy Turner  I use it to get the most convenient route according to lexical order

Comment: you don't use `lexic` after the `begin=lexic.get(0);` line, do you?

Comment: @Andy Turner No i don't use that ,but i need lexic in order to sort results with comparator

Answer (score 0):

This issue is occurring because of `lexic.sort()` , Java creates an additional copy of the elements on the heap so now you have twice the memory permitted for solution of the problem. In order to solve it you must use graph traversal techniques for a Directed Cyclic graph and make decisions based on lexical ordering, there is no need for `lexic` or using the sort method.

Answer (score 0):

Most sites offering a coding environment with algorithmic problems to solve (i.e Leetcode) impose specific limits on time/memory that must be met in order to consider a solution as "accepted". Therefore, your solution is probably correct but it uses more memory than expected.

In some way, it means that your solution's space complexity is not optimal. Keep in mind that java Stream API incurs extra memory overhead, so I would suggest you to avoid them.